# Multiple Sort order in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, sorting

I currently have a pretty standard magento setup. I have the general sort orders, price, release date, name.

What I want to do is add an extra level to each sort order. So they would be release date, price.

Comment: There are couple of methods available for multiple sort order. here i am mentioning one of it.

e.g. consider you have magento collection in  `$collection` variable.

You can write  `$collection->getSelect()->order("release date asc')->order('price desc')->order('name desc');`

Here **release date** would be first **price** would be second  and so on.

You can order the field as per your need

Comment: Could you give us more information about what you want? It's really not clear this moment...

Comment: Hey, many thanks for the reply, that is exactly what I need to achieve. Do you know what file this is in for the standard list page? Thanks again

Comment: Basically if I have a sort order for release date, I have a lot of products with the same date, so I want a secondary sort of price